# How to get slider value from .kv file to python file in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am not sure how to get the slider value from a .kv file to the python file.

My .kv file is:

```
<MyGrid>
    slider: slider
    Slider:
      id: slider2
      min: 0
      max: 23
      step: 1
      orientation: 'horizontal'
      pos: 530,400
    Button:
      text:"Start"
      on_press: root.btn()
      pos: 350,120
```

And my python file is:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.lang import Builder
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')



class MyGrid(Widget):
    slider = ObjectProperty(None)
    def btn(self):
        print(self.slider.text)
       


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyApp().run()
```

What am I doing wrong? I get an error that reads:

AttributeError: 'Slider' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

Your **id**, **btn function** and **main layout** are *incorrect*.So i fixed'em all.You can get slider's value , not text. You need to use boxlayout,floatlayout,gridlayout (etc.) for main layout. Widget is not layout. So your widgets(like button and others) disappear. Check code below.

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
kv = Builder.load_string("""
<MyGrid>
    slider: slider
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: str(slider.value)
        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0
            max: 23
            orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: "Print Value"
            on_press: root.btn()
""")
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
class MyGrid(BoxLayout):
    slider = ObjectProperty()
    def btn(self):
        print(self.slider.value)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```